# React call a function from another class ES6

Tags: javascript, function, class, reactjs, methods

```js
class F1 extends React.Component{
  hot(){
    alert("Hot function running");
  }
  lot(){
    let t = this;
    
      ReactDOM.render(<F2 yF={() => {
      t.hot();
    }} />,document.getElementById("b"));
  }
  render(){ 
     return (
      <button onClick={this.lot}>F1 click</button>
    );
  }
}
class F2 extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.yF}>F2 click</button>
    );
  }  
}

 ReactDOM.render(<F1 />,document.getElementById("a"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body> 
  
  <div id="a"></div>
  
  
  <div id="b"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/poqofohiqa/edit?html,js,console,output

I want to call a function that is inside `class F1` when i *click* `Button F2` the function inside F1 should be executed.

Currently im trying to pass the function from F1 to F2 but its not working

### UPDATE 1

To make it simple ...

Im trying to call `hot` function inside `F1` by clicking the button on `F2`

Comment: What's that `ReactDOM.render` call for?

Comment: `lot` function should not do what it actually does (calling `ReactDOM.render`). You should do this outside the component.

Comment: It seems to work. Clicking the F1 button adds the F2 button. Clicking the F2 button triggers the alert.

Comment: Yeah - it is working. What do you mean it is not working ?

Comment: It's not clear to me at *all* what this code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: @ArshabhAgarwal i didnt wrote the complete  code...see the updated version....im trying to change  value of `this` of F1 from  F2

Comment: @IMOBAMA: *"trying to change value of `this` of F1 from F2"* You can't change the value of `this` within a function, only when calling functions. And change it to what? From what? What's the actual end goal?

Comment: Rather than trying to explain this code, describe the problem you're trying to solve with it. Whatever problem you're trying to solve this is almost certainly not the correct approach.

Comment: @DaveNewton see my updated explanation in question .......

Comment: `this` would be undefined in this case

Comment: @ArshabhAgarwal yes its undefined. how do i pass this from F1 to F2 ? I updated my original code with much simpler example.

Comment: @IMOBAMA Understood that you're trying to call that, I just can't make heads or tails of the code you have or what you're actually trying to *do*. Because of that confusion, it's impossible to help. I'd consider taking a step back and at least making the code a bit more React-y before proceeding much further--you're heading down a dark path at the moment.

Comment: @IMOBAMA you need to bind the lot function with this. See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind lot method to this in `constructor` method. Then only it will get the context

```js
class F1 extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.lot = this.lot.bind(this);
  }
  hot(){
    alert("Hot function running");
  }
  lot(){              
      ReactDOM.render(<F2 yF={() => {
       this.hot();
      }} />,document.getElementById("b"));
  }
  render(){ 
     return (
      <button onClick={this.lot}>F1 click</button>
    );
  }
}
class F2 extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.yF}>F2 click</button>
    );
  }  
}

 ReactDOM.render(<F1 />,document.getElementById("a"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body> 
  
  <div id="a"></div>
  
  
  <div id="b"></div>

</body>
</html>
```